# Can I use a 1/4 turn valve in place of multi turn valve for toilet?

Tags: plumbing

Can a [quarter turn valve](https://www.homedepot.com/p/BrassCraft-1-2-in-Nominal-Compression-Inlet-x-3-8-in-O-D-Compression-Outlet-1-4-Turn-Angle-Valve-G2CR19X-C1/202047059) like this...

[image]

be used in place of the [traditional toilet valves](https://www.homedepot.com/p/BrassCraft-1-2-in-Nominal-Compression-Inlet-x-3-8-in-O-D-Compression-Outlet-Multi-Turn-Angle-Valve-OCR19X-C1/202047058) like this?

[image]

I ask because I recently replace the later with the former and it makes this strange "hissing" noise every time the toilet fills up. I suspect it is due to the very small outlet hole inside the "top" of the 1/4 turn valve that literally sprays water into the braided tube that connects to the toilet. Any ideas?

*(pictures from the respective HD web pages)*

Comment: Yes they sure can be used in their place - mine are exactly that way. The issue might be one has a slightly smaller diameter pass through than the other. If you change the flow rate of your fill valve in the toilet a little bit - (there is probably a screw somewhere on it), you can test/verify/fix the issue of the hissing. They are both 1/2 x 3/8 - how they work internally is where I suspect your issue is. You could also try a different brand of 1/4 turn valve. Mine work just fine - I bought them at lowes and they are not the same brand as HD, and they were much cheaper than that one too.

Comment: To be honest I think the noise is coming from where the water "squirts" out of the top of the 1/4 valve and hits the braided tube (which isn't completely straight) so it probably directly hits the sidewall of the tube. I'm not sure why the opening is a little bit bigger than 1/8in inside the valve itself. I will try adjusting the flow rate, otherwise, I will try a different valve. Any suggestions welcome in advance!

Comment: The water hitting the tube - easy to find out put the hose into a bucket and turn the valve on. On the fill valve you should find a screw that adjusts the fill rate . (Not tank level.)

Comment: Thank you for the useful troubleshooting tips! I will investigate it.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah nothing wrong. You could use either or. Only difference between quarter turn and multi turn is the actual turn method. Quarter turns require to go a “quarter of the way of a full turn”. Multi turns requires continuous turns. Depending on what type of pipe you have coming up is the most important. Not all shut off valves will work for each other. And most sizes are 1/2x3/8. But there is also 1/2x1/2